# Getting user's current location

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get user's current location base on the accuracy and less battery consumption.

Please review my code to help determine if I am going in right direction.

```
Location location = null;
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_
try {
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 5,locationListener);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    lati = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
    longi = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last know location could be null. So you need a further check for this, then ask for a quick update:

```
   if(location == null){
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            if (provider != null){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, singeUpdateListener, context.getMainLooper()); 
            }else {
                Log.e("TAG", No location set");             
            }
    }
```

class variable:

```
protected LocationListener singeUpdateListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String lati = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            String longi = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            locationManager.removeUpdates(singeUpdateListener);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };
```